# Delphi style that doesn't look old

Tags: delphi, themes, vcl

I'm creating a VCL application and I want to style it exactly like Delphi itself is styled. For example, the tree view nodes when selected render really nicely (full width blue bar), see below

[image]

Yet mine looks like it's from Windows 98:

[image]

I'm hoping there's an easy way to get this to look nicer. Would love any ideas or pointers in the right direction. I've never done any custom/owner drawing before so this is new to me.

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using? Recent version have styling facility and you can have it looks like a Win10 application.

Comment: Use VCL styles if this is what you want. Although don't be surprised if you find many defects once you do this. That's the trade off that you face.

Comment: Personally, I would definitely choose a well-behaved, bug- and flicker-free Win 95-like GUI over a buggy, odd, flickering, inaccessible, "modern-looking" one. All the time.

Comment: And to clarify David's comment: if you really want to, you can enable VCL styles by going to the `Appearance` node in the dialog box in your screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

For a starter, you could just experiment a little with the available standard property settings. The following is the looks of the standard `TTreeView` on Windows 10, with just a few properties changed.

[image]

From the `TextView` of the form:

```
  object TreeView1: TTreeView
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 225
    Height = 283
    Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWindowText
    Font.Height = -13
    Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
    Font.Style = []
    HideSelection = False
    HotTrack = True
    Indent = 19
    ParentFont = False
    RowSelect = True
    ShowLines = False
    TabOrder = 0
  end
```

Note the `Hottrack = true`, `Rowselect = true` and `Showlines = False`

Comment: And for an even more modern look, use Segoe UI, 9 pt.